# How to block my website from all the web

Tags: search-engine

I have a website and it should not be accessible from any one without the URL or any search engines.

No search engine should be aware of my website, only the person with the link should access it. Can some one suggest the best ideas since I'm going to share my office data's on it.

Comment: Are you asking how to 'secure' data? If so, 'hiding it from search engines' is going to do little to nothing in terms of securing it. You need to place your data behind a secure login.

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent most search engines from indexing your site with a robots.txt file. More details here: http://www.robotstxt.org/

However, this is not very secure. Some robots ignore robots.txt. The best way to restrict access is either to require a user to log in before entering the site, or use a firewall to allow only that user's IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a robots.txt file to the root folder of your website indicating that search engine spiders should not index tour website.

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

But its left to the search engines to read the file. Most popular search engines do honor this file. Another method is to not have a index.htm or default.htm in your website Even if it exists, remove any links to internal pages. This way spiders will never know the site structure of your website.

Comment: thanks for your information , but in my case my private website get indexed already in many search engine , can you help me in removing this

Comment: You will have to contact Google and other search engines and ask them to remove the content. This is a long process. I suggest you change your site structure. Make subtle changes to your folder/file names. This is faster and definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  OK:

1)  robots.txt
http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

2)  Authentication.  If you're using apache, password protect the site

3)  Ensure no one ever links to it from anywhere.

4)  Consider a different alternative, like dropbox.
http://www.dropbox.com/